# Prism4 and Windows Forms

Tags: wpf, winforms, prism

I have an WPF-Application composed with prism4(and MEF). Now I got the scenario that I need to run this WPF-Modules in a WindowsForms-Environment.
Should be able to do so with ElementHosts in WinForms, but how do I setup the prism4-environment??

Greets,

Jürgen